# How would you guys handle this problem, Hover over text in nav bar, increases the space between all content

Tags: html, css

As you guys can see because there as a margin to space out the contents inside the NAVBAR, when I increase the font size it pushes everything to the left or right more. Is there way to add blank space or something in-between the margins so it can use that extra space freely without pushing the contents to the left or to the right depending on what I am hovering over.

```css
@media only screen and (min-width: 1920px){
    body {
        background-color: #F0F2F5;
            width:1920px;
            height:800px;
        }
    }
    
    #JGLogo {
        position: relative;
        top:8px;
        left:-250px;
    }
    .NavBar {
        margin-top: 15px;
        text-align: center;
        width:100%;
        height:10%;
        background-color: white;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #E3E3FF;
    }
    .NavBar a {
        position: relative;
        top:-15px;
        margin-right: 55px;
        
        font-size: 32px;
        color: #62ACFF;    
        text-decoration: none; 
    }
    .NavBar a:hover {
        font-size: 36px;
    }
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href ="Layout.css">
        <title>JGardam</title>
        
        <div class="NavBar">
            <img id="JGLogo" src="Images/JGLogo.png">
            <a href = "">Home</a>
            <a href = "">About Me</a>
        </div>
    </head>
    <body></body>
    <footer></footer>
</html>
```

Comment: You have your content in the document `<head />`-- it may not be the source of your problem, but it is for sure incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, as stated in the comment above, the `head` tag should not contain any markup. You must put the markup inside the `body` tag.

I would solve this problem by using rule `transform: scale()` for tag `a:hover`. Like this:

```
.NavBar a:hover {
    transform: scale(1.1);
}
```

Also, you should set these rules for the tag `a`:

```
.NavBar a {
    ...
    transition: .5s;
    display: inline-block;   
    ...
}
```

```css
#JGLogo{
    position: relative;
    top:8px;
    left:-250px;
}
.NavBar{
    margin-top: 15px;
    text-align: center;
    width:100%;
    height:10%;
    background-color: white;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #E3E3FF;
}
.NavBar a{
    position: relative;
    top:-15px;
    margin-right: 55px;
    transition: .5s;
    display: inline-block;
    
    
    font-size: 32px;
    color: #62ACFF;    
    text-decoration: none;
    
    
}
.NavBar a:hover{
    /*font-size: 36px;*/
    transform: scale(1.1);
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1920px){
    body{
        background-color: #F0F2F5;
        width:1920px;
        height:800px;
    }
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
     
    </head>

    <body>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href ="Layout.css">
        <title>JGardam</title>
    
        
        <div class="NavBar">
             <img id="JGLogo" src="Images/JGLogo.png">
            <a href = "">Home</a>
            <a href = "">About Me</a>
        </div>
    
    </body>
    
    <footer></footer>

</html>
```

Comment: It is probably worth noting that the `<head />` should not contain any markup other than `script`s, `link`s and other metadata...

Comment: @AlexanderNied, Yes, I didn't pay attention. Fixed this.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up guys, I moved everything to the body and won't put anything else in the head except scripts and titles. It seems Transform: scale isn't doing anything. Maybe i have to set the position to absolute or something ?

Comment: @Jake, You also need to add `display: inline-block;` and `transition: .5s;` to `.NavBar a`. See my updated answer, please.

Comment: Yeah I saw that, so I fixed the problem. I removed the margins from the NAVBAR class, so my logo didn't take the margin properties. So now my logo doesn't shift to the left during the animations. One more quick question, I've looked all over google, and can't seem to find an answer about how I should be positioning things (the professional proper way) I'm assuming position:relative, with percent based positions is the best method ? compared to absolute and specific pixels right ?

Comment: @Jake, In modern times, programmers and site designers use flex and grid rules. These are very useful tools for layout design. Read articles on flex and grid. But again, it all depends on the layout of your site and the task at hand, as well as on the desired result. Sometimes, relative or absolute positioning is also required. for example, to create menus and drop-down menu items.

Comment: @sergeykuznetsov Oh haha, got it. Thank you very much

Comment: @Jake, always glad to help :)